# Format error when using Bosun save hook

Tags: bosun

I get the following error while attempting to use the "save hook" functionality in Bosun -

`failed to call save hook: fork/exec /tools/bosun/bin/save-hook: exec format error. Restoring config: successful`

The file is executable and I've removed all logic from it, and the error still occurs.

Should the file return anything? Or is this a bug?
The documentation indicates it should be successful as long as the hook exits ok.

https://bosun.org/system_configuration#commandhookpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess the OS is not accepting this as a proper executable?

1. If a binary, did you compile it on the same system, or make sure your cross compiled it for the right architecture?
2. If a script, does your script have the [bang](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87560/does-the-shebang-determine-the-shell-which-runs-the-script) line at the start, for example `#!/bin/bash`?

Comment: Exactly right. I didn't have a hash bang in the script. Thanks!